# HOME anchor doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

http://paladolphin.com
The Home link isn't working.  So, "Craig Lance Photography" has a `<a>` tag that brings you back home.  I've used the inspector and it clearly has the `<a>` tag which points to "http://paladolphin.com/".
`<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://paladolphin.com/" title="Craig Lance Photography" rel="home">Craig Lance Photography</a>`
It fails to display the URL on hover and clicking on it does nothing.
Here's what I know about it:

1. It only fails on the live server.  It works on the local development server.  They should be identical.
2. Fails the same way on every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera).
3. I don't know what this attribute does: rel="home".  It's not in PHP syntax.  It's probably not relevant since I've removed it and the problem still exists.
4. Both live and dev are new WP 4.7.1 installs.  They only differ in that I used Softlicous to install it live where I downloaded WP from WordPress.org for my dev server.  Since then I've have done the same things to each server (added pages, plugins, themes, etc.) to keep them identical.

I saved the HTML page locally as a `.html` file, opened it on my local Apache server and it fails.  I'm currently debugging it to determine what is causing it. But, even if I find the cause, how do I get WordPress to do the right thing?

Comment: As far as I know, both the `title=""` and the `rel=""` are unnecessary.

Comment: what is the `class="navbar-brand"` doing? I'd imagine something like: `content: "git trolled"`

Comment: You shouldn't link to existing sites that might not last the test of time. Post the relevant code in your question so if someone comes to this years from now after your website is gone and has a similar issue they can find answers.

Comment: It was Contact Bank Lite Edition plugin. When I disable it, the problem disappears.

Comment: It was Contact Bank Lite Edition plugin. When I disable it, the problem disappears. I was experimenting with contact form plugins; this just happened to be one that didn't work as desired. I never put it on my dev server. Yeah, I know, why are you experimenting live? I was running out the door to a photo meetup and had to get something going fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a `z-index` issue, You can add following `CSS` to solve your problem

```
.navbar-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: That worked.  I'll have to study up on z-index stuff.  Thanks.

Comment: @PalaDolphin if this resolves it, accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: You can read following documents for how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I want to thank Super User and the others who came to my mental rescue on this question.  I was pulling my hair out; they may be gray, by they're all I've got.

Comment: Oh, and thanks Super User for the link on accepting the correct answer.